# Excel formula for validating cell formats

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I work for the NHS in England, and I often have to validate files I received with long lists of NHS Nos. Is there a formula that replicates, or is equivalent/similar to Access's "Like" or "Not Like".

Specifically, the NHS No has the format nnn nnn nnnn? How do I find those values in the list which do not fit this format?

Answer (score 1):

We can check multiple conditions within `AND` command wrapped in `IF`:

1. 4th character is space
2. 8th character is space
3. first 3 numbers are numeric
4. 5th to 7 characters are numeric
5. last 3 characters are numeric
6. length is 12

**Note:** having 10 digits doesn't make a valid NHS number. Also, valid NHS number doesn't mean it exists.

```
=IF(
    AND(
        MID(A1,4,1) = " ",
        MID(A1,8,1) = " ",
        ISNUMBER(
            VALUE(
                LEFT(A1,3))),
        ISNUMBER(
            VALUE(
                MID(A1,5,3))),
        ISNUMBER(
            VALUE(
                RIGHT(A1,4))),
        LEN(A1) = 12
        ),
        "valid",
        "invalid"
        )
```

[image]

Or we can use VBA function, see [here for an example](https://healthanalyst.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/nhs-number-validation/)

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll have to have a look at VBA function, when I've some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that would be to use custom AutoFilters. To do so, simply activate the filters for your table, then select 'custom filters' in the filter options. It will give you an option window, where you can choose which critera you want to adopt yo filter your data, and only keep the data with a 'XXX_XXX_XXXX' format.

You can watch this [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-custom-autofilter-on-an-excel-table.html) for more information about the possibilities of theses filters.

If you can't use filters but you need a formula, you can use the following formula to check if the data correspond to your required format :

```
=MATCH("??? ??? ????"; A1;0)
```

It will return 1 if the data correspond to a XXX_XXX_XXXX format (X could be a letter or a digit, since you did not precise in your question here.)

Comment: Many thanks for this - I think the match function is where I'd want to go.